# how to add more than one hostname support for https configuration ? like i want to access using domain as well as ip address using https

Tags: ssl, https, jboss, keytool

iam using jboss application server.
created my own self signed certificate using keytool key and certificate management tool and configured this certificate in jboss configuration file.
for accessing different applications like in my case using web service calls between applications using https, imported my own self signed certificate to java run time environment trusted keystore i.e, cacerts.
my question is i want to access the application with ip address as well as my domain using https.
any suggestions ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask How do I ask a good question?

Comment: Please show what you have already done

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your self-signed certificate look like this:

[image]

In the certificate SubjectAltName extension, you need to add the `dnsName` and `ipAddress` extensions to it.

You could use KeyStore Explorer GUI tool to create them.